# How to get facebook friends profile pic list in flex 4.5 mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using FacebookMobile api. I am getting the friends id and name but not the images.
Using the below code.

```
 FacebookMobile.api("/me/friends", getStatusHandler);
```

Can any one please suggest me how i can get list of firends profile pics along with id and name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should use FQL to get the rest of the information;

http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn-history/r333/trunk/examples/FriendsListMobile_Flash/demo/models/FriendModel.as

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot Jonatan. I have been looking for exactly that kind of class.